# Help on solving non-linear 2nd Order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I need help on solving the nonlinear equation: $x^3y''(x)-y(x)y'(x)=0$.
*Mathematica* simply repeats the above equation in the output.

Input:

```
DSolve[x^3*y''[x]-y[x]*y'[x]==0,y[x],x]
```

Comment: Maple performs a complicated expression which is too long to be cited here.

Comment: In the book by Micheal Greenberg, the solution to this equation is y1=1 and y2=x^2; yet their linear combination 4+3x^2 is not. This is under the section: Superposition of Solutions for Homogeneous Equation (General Solution).